# Country/State Dynamic Drop Down List in Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

> I need a city/state/country Dynamic Drop-Down List in my Wordpress registration page.
>
> I have putted some entries manually.

[This is my Registration Page link](http://izisstechnology.com/dashboard/wp-login.php?action=register&redirect_to=/dashboard/dash-board)

Comment: you can use plugins for that.. that is very easy to implement..

Comment: Can you give me some suggestion. I have tried but I didn't find any such plugin, for custom city/state/country dynamic drop-down field in my registration form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for plugin so , i used one before couple of months:-

try this:-

http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/drop-down-post-list-plugin-for-wordpress/

Drop-Down Post List Plugin for WordPress

Comment: thanks for the help, but can you tell me, how can i use this as a custom field in my registration page.

Comment: one create shortcode and use.. or see the process in readme file or check that url